# Reactive: Latest value to be received by IObservable

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive

I know that the following is a blocking call and will return the first value in the observable sequence:

```
var result = myObservable.First();
```

Depending on what type of subject I use this has different implications:

- Subject - First() will block until the OnNext() is next called which means eventually **this will be the latest value**
- BehaviorSubject - First() will block until at least one value has been pushed through OnNext() and because BehaviorSubject tracks the last value **this will be the latest value**
- ReplaySubject - First() will block until at least one value has been pushed through OnNext(), but in the case that many items have been pushed through OnNext it will be the first on in its buffer **which is NOT the last one**

Now I am trying to find a consistent way of getting the last value regardless of which underlying Observable is used.

Any ideas?

Comment: By the way, I believe that BehaviorSubject will not block - it will return the default value that is provided which it is created until a new value is pumped, and then it'll return that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your other Rx question, I think you want this:

```
var rootSubject = new ReplaySubject<Types>();
var firstSubject = rootSubject.Where(x => x == Types.First);
var secondSubject = rootSubject.Where(x => x == Types.Second);
var thirdSubject = rootSubject.Where(x => x == Types.Third);
var forthSubject = rootSubject.Where(x => x == Types.Fourth);

var mergedSubject = Observable
              .Merge(firstSubject, secondSubject, thirdSubject, forthSubject)
        .Timeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2), Observable.Return(Types.Error))    
        .Replay();

mergedSubject.Connect();

rootSubject.OnNext(Types.First);
rootSubject.OnNext(Types.Second);

var result = mergedSubject.First();

rootSubject.OnNext(Types.Third);
rootSubject.OnNext(Types.Fourth);

Console.WriteLine(String.Format("result - {0}", result));
```

Now it doesn't matter what kind of Subject is used, they all return "result - First".

If you want the latest value before calling mergedSubject.First(), you'd use Replay(1):

```
var mergedSubject = Observable
                .Merge(firstSubject, secondSubject, thirdSubject, forthSubject)
                .Timeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2), Observable.Return(Types.Error))    
                .Replay(1);
```

In which case, all Subject types will return "result - Second".

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you're looking for `Replay` (which, in the latest version, is functionally equivalent to using `Multicast` with a `ReplaySubject`):

```
IObservable<int> source = SomeHotObservable();

IConnectableObservable<int> sourceWithOneBufferedValue = source.Replay(1);

IDisposable subscription = sourceWithOneBufferedValue.Connect();

source.OnNext(5);

sourceWithOneBufferedValue.Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
```